# Sparql in progete to get individual of a defined class

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, protege4

I have designed an ontology. there is a defined class base on some properties. when I am running protege reasoner it is showing me the individual that is member of that defined class. but i m not being able to retrieve the member of that defined class using sparql in protege.
can any body help? i am attaching the screen shot.[image: sparql query result] [image: after reasoning member of defined class]

Comment: Control ++ to large it

Comment: The results in the first screenshot are clipped at the bottom.  Just to cover the bases, are you sure the desired class doesn't appear farther down in that list?  The other question, I suppose, is whether or not the SPARQL query is run over data that includes output from the reasoner.  If it isn't, then you wouldn't expect to see the result.

Comment: In the first screenshot there is only four result. I am pretty much sure. I also tried to find the answer of your second question. in some cases people are saying the it should be found means includes output from reasoner.